# Undefined variable with string

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Inside profuser variable i have string "nick".

> echo a href="#"  onclick="prof('.$profuser.')">

@UP I DELETED THE SIGN BEFORE a BECOUSE IT WAS DESTROYING WHOLE CODE IN STACK OVERFLOW

It should be sent here:

```
<script>
 function prof(profuser){ 
var xmlhttp=new
 window.XMLHttpRequest(); xmlhttp.open("GET", "user.php?user=" +
 profuser, true); xmlhttp.send(); } 
</script>
```

And then to this file called user.php:

```
$thisuser = $_GET['user']; echo $thisuser;
```

But this code shows me that string "nick" is not defined.
Could anyone tell me what is wrong about it please?
And if there are more errors in this code tell me please.

Comment: The first parameter to `open` should be a string, e.g. `xmlhttp.open('GET', ...)`. Also when you're trying to pass the variable to `prof` in the `onclick` attribute, you need to properly quote / escape the variable as a JavaScript string, e.g. `onclick="prof('.json_encode($profuser).')"`

Comment: What tells you that "nick is not defined"?  It's not really clear what you're talking about.

Comment: onclick says that it is not defined i guess but im new at debugging

Comment: If the $profuser is being generated by php then you should use onclick="prof('<?php echo $profuser;?>')"

Comment: my onclick is a link inside echo in php already.
Sorry i didnt post it but was too much code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error say nick is treated as undefined variable. It should be seen as string so you need to add quotes:

```
onclick="prof(\'' . addslashes($profuser) . '\')"
```

According to @p.s.w.g, you should use [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) to escape quotes from php variable in case there were any;)

Comment: But what is wrong about the quotes i already added?

Comment: Your single quotes are phrased by php on server side guotes are needed also on client side.

Comment: This will work until you have a professor named `o'neill`. You'd need to properly escape the value too.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
onclick="prof('<?php echo $profuser; ?>')"
```

or

```
onclick="prof('<?= $profuser; ?>')"
```

I think you are mixing PHP and javascript? Hard to tell from the limited code that was posted.

Your issue is most likely a quoting one, if you are printing the whole onclick bit try this

```
echo 'onclick="prof(\''.$profuser.'\')"';
```

This is because you are probably getting something like this in your source.

```
onclick="prof(nick)";
```

And nick is a string not a javascript variable, which will be undefined.

Comment: my onclick is a link inside echo in php already.
Sorry i didnt post it but was too much code

Comment: well if it's to much code it needs to be simplified.  Anyway, it's hard to help without seeing how you get the onclick bit

Comment: I will edit my first post in 1 second

Comment: you need quotes around nick,

Comment: omg i cant edit post properly, the code cuts in half and cannot see it here in a half but i deleted few signs and accepted

Comment: Yea thank you :) I will ++ your post when i get more reputation i cant now :/